# Show that there exists k such that $\mu(E_k) \geq m/n$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose that $\mu(X)=1$. Let  $E_1, E_2, \dotsc, E_n$ be measurable subsets of
>   $X$, and each point of $X$ belongs to at least $m$ of these sets. Show
>   that there exists $k$ such that $\mu(E_k) \geq m/n$.

There is no information about whether $E_n$ are disjoint or not? If these sets are disjoint then is it going to be easy? Can you suggest me some hints.

Comment: What can you say about $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \mu(E_k)$?

Comment: you mean at least 1 @ DF

Comment: Further hint then: what kind of functions is this $\sum_{k=1}^n\,\chi_{E_k}-m\chi_X$, where $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function supported on $S$?